# Read Apple crash reports without OS

Tags: ios, react-native, crash, expo

So I built an app on expo with react native that run perfectly on android, I am using a Windows pc for my code and also uploaded with application uploader, 
So I got an an error report from apple, first of all how do I understand what is the reason my app is crashing? there is a way to understand the errors without Mac pc? Thanks!

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191632ebc 0x19160e000 + 151228
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019154e790 0x19154c000 + 10128
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001914a28a0 0x19142f000 + 473248
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001914a2830 0x19142f000 + 473136
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001915fb7d4 0x1915fa000 + 6100
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001915fb9c4 0x1915fa000 + 6596
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000191563358 0x19155d000 + 25432
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191608304 0x1915fa000 + 58116
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019160829c 0x1915fa000 + 58012
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191508198 0x1914ac000 + 377240
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914bad14 0x1914ac000 + 60692
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191508184 0x1914ac000 + 377220
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914ba1d0 0x1914ac000 + 57808
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b83c4 0x19170f000 + 693188
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b33b8 0x19170f000 + 672696
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b28bc 0x19170f000 + 669884
16  GraphicsServices                0x000000019b61e328 0x19b61b000 + 13096
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001958486d4 0x194e58000 + 10421972
18  ComGpLiminal                    0x0000000100818658 0x100814000 + 18008
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019163d460 0x19163c000 + 5216

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aad8 0x19154c000 + 60120

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aad8 0x19154c000 + 60120

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aad8 0x19154c000 + 60120

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aad8 0x19154c000 + 60120

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001916338b0 0x19160e000 + 153776
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914aecfc 0x1914ac000 + 11516
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914aeae0 0x1914ac000 + 10976
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914baee4 0x1914ac000 + 61156
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914bab00 0x1914ac000 + 60160
5   ComGpLiminal                    0x00000001009fa6b0 0x100814000 + 1992368
6   ComGpLiminal                    0x00000001009e5c70 0x100814000 + 1907824
7   ComGpLiminal                    0x0000000100ba92bc 0x100814000 + 3756732
8   ComGpLiminal                    0x0000000100bdf33c 0x100814000 + 3978044
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191840d90 0x19170f000 + 1252752
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191710bd0 0x19170f000 + 7120
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917117a8 0x19170f000 + 10152
12  ComGpLiminal                    0x0000000100c07860 0x100814000 + 4143200
13  ComGpLiminal                    0x0000000100c0e0cc 0x100814000 + 4169932
14  ComGpLiminal                    0x0000000100c0de2c 0x100814000 + 4169260
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191507610 0x1914ac000 + 374288
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191508184 0x1914ac000 + 377220
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914b4464 0x1914ac000 + 33892
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914b4e58 0x1914ac000 + 36440
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914be340 0x1914ac000 + 74560
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191557fa4 0x19154c000 + 49060
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aae0 0x19154c000 + 60128

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aad8 0x19154c000 + 60120

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001916115f4 0x19160e000 + 13812
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191610a60 0x19160e000 + 10848
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b8068 0x19170f000 + 692328
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b3188 0x19170f000 + 672136
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b28bc 0x19170f000 + 669884
5   Foundation                      0x0000000191af2994 0x191aeb000 + 31124
6   Foundation                      0x0000000191af2874 0x191aeb000 + 30836
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001958e049c 0x194e58000 + 11043996
8   Foundation                      0x0000000191c230b0 0x191aeb000 + 1278128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001915571ec 0x19154c000 + 45548
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aaec 0x19154c000 + 60140

Thread 8 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001916115f4 0x19160e000 + 13812
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191610a60 0x19160e000 + 10848
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b8068 0x19170f000 + 692328
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b3188 0x19170f000 + 672136
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b28bc 0x19170f000 + 669884
5   AVFAudio                        0x000000019e213e68 0x19e1ae000 + 417384
6   AVFAudio                        0x000000019e264df0 0x19e1ae000 + 749040
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001915571ec 0x19154c000 + 45548
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aaec 0x19154c000 + 60140

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aad8 0x19154c000 + 60120

Thread 10 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001916115f4 0x19160e000 + 13812
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191610a60 0x19160e000 + 10848
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b8068 0x19170f000 + 692328
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b3188 0x19170f000 + 672136
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b28bc 0x19170f000 + 669884
5   ComGpLiminal                    0x0000000100bca6b4 0x100814000 + 3892916
6   Foundation                      0x0000000191c230b0 0x191aeb000 + 1278128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001915571ec 0x19154c000 + 45548
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aaec 0x19154c000 + 60140

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001916115f4 0x19160e000 + 13812
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191610a60 0x19160e000 + 10848
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b8068 0x19170f000 + 692328
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b3188 0x19170f000 + 672136
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b28bc 0x19170f000 + 669884
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b3608 0x19170f000 + 673288
6   CoreMotion                      0x000000019e0d264c 0x19dfec000 + 943692
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001915571ec 0x19154c000 + 45548
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aaec 0x19154c000 + 60140

Thread 12 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191632c8c 0x19160e000 + 150668
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191550204 0x19154c000 + 16900
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001916847a8 0x191676000 + 59304
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a04103fc 0x1a0388000 + 558076
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a0413dcc 0x1a0388000 + 572876
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a0413ab4 0x1a0388000 + 572084
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a0414dc0 0x1a0388000 + 576960
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001915571ec 0x19154c000 + 45548
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aaec 0x19154c000 + 60140

Thread 13 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001916115f4 0x19160e000 + 13812
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191610a60 0x19160e000 + 10848
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b8068 0x19170f000 + 692328
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b3188 0x19170f000 + 672136
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001917b28bc 0x19170f000 + 669884
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000194a2de68 0x194a2c000 + 7784
6   Foundation                      0x0000000191c230b0 0x191aeb000 + 1278128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001915571ec 0x19154c000 + 45548
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aaec 0x19154c000 + 60140

Thread 14 name:  Heap Helper Thread
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191632c8c 0x19160e000 + 150668
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191550204 0x19154c000 + 16900
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03d4b6c 0x1a0388000 + 314220
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03baa18 0x1a0388000 + 207384
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03932d4 0x1a0388000 + 45780
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a039365c 0x1a0388000 + 46684
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03d27a4 0x1a0388000 + 305060
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03d4314 0x1a0388000 + 312084
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001915571ec 0x19154c000 + 45548
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aaec 0x19154c000 + 60140

Thread 15 name:  Heap Helper Thread
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191632c8c 0x19160e000 + 150668
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191550204 0x19154c000 + 16900
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03d4b6c 0x1a0388000 + 314220
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03baa18 0x1a0388000 + 207384
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03932d4 0x1a0388000 + 45780
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a039365c 0x1a0388000 + 46684
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03d27a4 0x1a0388000 + 305060
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03d4314 0x1a0388000 + 312084
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001915571ec 0x19154c000 + 45548
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aaec 0x19154c000 + 60140

Thread 16 name:  JSC Heap Collector Thread
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191632c8c 0x19160e000 + 150668
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191550204 0x19154c000 + 16900
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03d4b6c 0x1a0388000 + 314220
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03baa18 0x1a0388000 + 207384
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03932d4 0x1a0388000 + 45780
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a039365c 0x1a0388000 + 46684
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03d27a4 0x1a0388000 + 305060
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a03d4314 0x1a0388000 + 312084
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001915571ec 0x19154c000 + 45548
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019155aaec 0x19154c000 + 60140

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000102f69800   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x00000001c708b080  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x000000000000004c
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x000000016f5ea5e0  x22: 0x0000000102f698e0  x23: 0x0000000102f698e0
   x24: 0x0000000000000013  x25: 0x000000016f8a2390  x26: 0x0000000102f698e0  x27: 0x00000000000020ff
   x28: 0x0000000002ffffff   fp: 0x000000016f5ea500   lr: 0x000000019154e790
    sp: 0x000000016f5ea4e0   pc: 0x0000000191632ebc cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pattern of library calls in that crashing thread, my guess you have an uncaught exception thrown from within a dispatch block. Most other threads appear to be parked, and aren't doing anything particularly interesting. The one labelled "com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue" is interesting, but I don't know enough about React Native to comment.

Unfortunately, this is really not much to go on.

It is technically possible to translate addresses into symbols (a process known as symbolication) without a Mac. But, it's going to be a real pain and requires a fair amount of knowledge about the underlying systems. Unfortunately, in this case, I don't think it's going to help you. All you'll see is confirmation that an uncaught exception was thrown. This report does not contain information about the exception itself, as I believe Apple strips that out.

You are going to need to reproduce this crash locally to see what's happening. Alternatively, you could look into a crash reporting system that integrates with React Native better, so it can capture the details for you. Good luck!